# Finding and replacing string (mac address) in a file is not working

Tags: python, regex, string, python-3.x

I've file that contain MAC among other information, I'm trying to replace the MAC every time it is found.
the file contains something like

```
Dec  3 06:44:02 2013 192.168.5.21 [245]: <1234> <NOTI> |machine1@192.168.5.21|
request: 55:aa:cc:77:dd:bb: machine 192.168.5.21-00:11:ee:20:66:22-device-name-5
```

I have wrote this code, but it's not working

```
import re

with open("/home/user/infile.txt", "r+") as fin:
        for line in fin:
            mac=re.search(r'([0-9A-F]{2}[:-]){5}([0-9A-F]{2})',line, re.I).group()
            for col in mac:
                mac_h = mac.replace(":",'')
            mac_hex = "0x" + mac_h
            mac_int= int(mac_hex, 16)
            new_mac = mac_int+12345
            new_mac= hex(new_mac)
            line= line.replace(mac, new_mac)
fin.close()
```

so I'm searching for mac, here I have two problems, first, it only finds the first occurrence of mac in the line. Second, when I tried the code on the second occurrence only, it got `21-00:11:ee:20:66:22` instead of just `00:11:ee:20:66:22`

and then I'm doing some arithmetics (this part works), but then when I tried to replace the old value with the new one. it didn't work, I checked the file, and nothing has be replace.
I can't figure out why, so can help me, please?

Update

I've changed the code, and now it write the changes to file

```
import re

with open("/home/user/infile.txt", "r+") as fin:
    with open("/home/user/infile.txt", "w+") as f_out:
        for line in fin:
            mac=re.search(r'([0-9A-F]{2}[:]){5}([0-9A-F]{2})',line, re.I).group()
            for col in mac:
                mac_h = mac.replace(":",'')
            mac_hex = "0x" + mac_h
            mac_int= int(mac_hex, 16)
            new_mac = mac_int+12345
            new_mac= hex(new_mac)
            line= line.replace(mac, new_mac)
            f_out.write(line)
```

now the remaining problem is that it only find the first mac occurrence `55:aa:cc:77:dd:bb:` and move to the next line without matching the second one `00:11:ee:20:66:22`, so is there a way to make it continue to search after finding the first match??
Thanks

Comment: if you're using `with`, then I don't think there's a reason to explicitly close the file.

Comment: You're not updating the file anywhere, you're just setting the variable `line`.

Comment: But I'm using `replace()` ??

Comment: That doesn't write the data back to the file! And if you don't want to match a dash, just use `:` instead of `[:-]`

Comment: thanks, that solved the issue of updating the file, but still it only changes the first occurrence of mac in the line, and not the second one, I'm wondering why.

Comment: Compile the pattern with `re.compile`. Use `os.rename` to rename the file. Open it for reading. Open a new file with the original name for writing. Loop over the lines of the file. Use the [`sub` method](http://docs.python.org/3/library/re#re.regex.sub) of the pattern with a function that transforms the MAC address for the match object. Use `os.remove` to delete the original file.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the hyphen from your regex. MAC adress components are usually separated with colons.

```
/([\dA-F]{2}:){5}([\dA-F]{2})/i
```